# Mysql add value (concat) at the beginning, not at the end?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so when user like a comment, my script adds user name to comments table, likes row.

```
$ben = "Rose,";

mysql_query("UPDATE comments set likes = CONCAT(comments.likes, 
'".$ben."') WHERE id ='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

However, it adds at the end of the list. For example if likes row have these;

John,Mark,Mary,

after it adds, its

John,Mark,Mary,**Rose,**

But I want it to add to the beginning, like

Rose,John,Mark,Mary,

How can I do that ?

Comment: Doesn't simply switching the order of your arguments to `CONCAT()` do what you want?

Comment: When using concat, it adds the new value at the end of the current value.

Comment: You should normalize your database and have a separate table to connect user-likes to comments and users. This will make it very hard and extremely inefficient to retrieve information.

Comment: I just use this method for performance issues.

Comment: @user3304007 . . . You don't seem to understand performance in databases.

Comment: If you profile and index your queries, doing what @jeroen says will make your DB go 1000 times better.

Comment: Btw... 1. Don't use the deprecated mysql_*-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @Magnus, I know how to index, but could you explain profile ?

Comment: Let me [Google that for you](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=profile%20your%20mysql%20queries). I ment that you should index your DB and profile your queries.. not index your queries...

Comment: [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) doesn't care, or even _know_, what the "current value" of a column is. It doesn't even need a column; it takes in _strings_ and outputs a _string_. See the `SELECT CONCAT('My', 'S', 'QL');` example in the linked documentation.

Comment: But concat means "add this if it doesnt contain this" ?

Comment: No it doesn't.. _"String concatenation is the operation of joining character strings end-to-end. For example, the concatenation of "snow" and "ball" is "snowball"_. If you concatenate "hello" with "hello", it will be "hellohello"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change arguments order [function_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
mysql_query("UPDATE comments set likes = CONCAT( 
'".$ben."',comments.likes) WHERE id ='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

With PDO:

```
use \PDO as PDO;
$PDO = new PDO('mysql:...');
$Stm = $PDO->prepare("UPDATE comments set likes = CONCAT(?,comments.likes) WHERE id =?");
$Stm->execute([$ben,$id]);
```

Comment: This does answer the question, but you should really show an example without the deprecated `mysql_*` and without the risk of SQL Injections. Then you would get one more upvote. We should all help out to promote best practices.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thx, PDO code added, i agree that it woud be a better word if everybody would have forgotten about `mysql_*`

Comment: Nice. Not only does it remove the risk of injections, it also makes it more readable.

Comment: So if I use PDO, there is no need for mysql_real_escape_string() and other protections ?

Comment: @user3304007 yes escaping handled by PDO